# TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s). python(django) how fix this error?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

**i have this error --> 
raise TypeError("'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): %s" % ','.join(meta_attrs))
TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): models**

**i want create page where people can register but i have this error. how fix?**

**i search google but  couldn't find a reason. what's the problem?**

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import password_validation
from django.db import models




class SignUp(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        models=User
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

views.py

```
from . import forms
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import  HttpResponse
import datetime
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate


def regform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUp(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUp()
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: A `Model` has no `model = ` (nor `models = `) in its `Meta`. This should be a `ModelForm`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem   class SignUp(models.ModelForm):
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'ModelForm'

Comment: it is `forms.ModelForm`, not `models.ModelForm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are here defining a `Model`, but you likely want to define a `ModelForm`. Note that the `Meta` of a `ModelForm` uses `model`, not `models`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUp(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

In the case of creating a `User` object, you better inherit from `UserCreationForm`, since this will store the *hashed* password in the database:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUp(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

By using a generic `ModelForm`, it will store the raw password in the form, and then authentication will fail (because this checks the hashed password).

Comment: raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form SignUp needs updating.

Comment: @kokiwebaa: well, you of course need to specify which fields you want to use in your `SignUp`. I would advise that you please read the error messages, instead of just copying.

Comment: form = SignUp()
NameError: name 'SignUp' is not defined.

Comment: @kokiwebaa: that is because you forgot to import this in your `views.py`.

Answer (score 1):

comment out

```
'rest_framework.authtoken',
```

then you will able to makemigrations and migrate also

Answer (score 0):

It should be **ModelForm** instead of models.Model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
class SignUp(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields = [add your fields here]
```

Comment: form = SignUp()
NameError: name 'SignUp' is not defined